# Css background image not showing up at all

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to display an image using background in css. 
For some strange reason it does not show up at all. I have tried various ways of doing this and googled but still nothing. Here's what I have:

```
<li class="col">
      <a href="{% url 'aboutme' %}">
        <div class="skillsIcon">
          <div class="ninja">

          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
```

Here's css:

```
.ninja {
   background: url('../images/ninja_circle.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto;
   width: 100px;
}
```

The only time when I got something was when I entered text inside the ninja class but it was cut in half.
I checked and the image is properly loaded, it just doesn't show up.
What can I do to make this work? I need to use it like this since I have another image to display when hovering.
Thanks!

Comment: Set a height to your ninja class and if your path is correct it will show.

Comment: `got something was when I entered text inside the ninja` : you have the answer ;)

Comment: have you tried using the background-image property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify width and`height` of the `div`. Else the `div` has `0` of `height`

```css
.ninja {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<li class="col">
  <a href="{% url 'aboutme' %}">
    <div class="skillsIcon">
      <div class="ninja">

      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I will accept this as an answer once i can. Could you tell me how can I center the backgroudn image as well?

Comment: Hi, you can use background-position . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: what @JonathanChaplin sayed

Answer (score 1):

Divs are collapsable and since there is no content in your div it has no height or width.

you could set `width:100%;` on .ninja (assuming the parent div spans the page) to fix this.